# Weird error when creating new Action Script class

Tags: apache-flex, class, actionscript, flexbuilder

Good Morning,

I have a very odd error working in adobe flexbuilder 3.

Ever since yesterday when ever I create a new class, Flex builder do not see anything wrong in my class.

how do i create one:

1. Right click on a folder in the package hierarchy
   --> new
   --> action script class
2. I leave everthing as is but i give it a name obviously
3. finish

The class is created.

I can now type anything into this class... Even the words "abc" and flex builder do not see that this is wrong.

if i go to an existing class and type "abs" , the moment i hit save it complains about the "abc"

I have tried the following but the problem still persists.

1. Deleted my workspace and created a new one and re-import.
2. If i right click on the class in the Flex navigator the "inlcude class in library" is greyed out.

if anyone can give me an idea, even if it is silly, please do. I really need to be able to add new classes.

thanks

The new class that i have created looks like

```
package za.co.dcs.cib.das.application.vo.authorisation.appDetails.memberDetails
{
    public class MyNewlyTestClass
    {
        public function MyNewlyTestClass()
        {
        }

    }
}
```

and then i add "ABC" to it... to which it don't complain about. I can add just about anything i want to this class... and nothing is ever an error.

```
package za.co.dcs.cib.das.application.vo.authorisation.appDetails.memberDetails
{
    public class MyNewlyTestClass
    {
        public function MyNewlyTestClass()
        {
        abc
        }

    }
}
```

Or if i remove the function

```
package za.co.dcs.cib.das.application.vo.authorisation.appDetails.memberDetails
{
    public class MyNewlyTestClass
    {
        public MyNewlyTestClass()
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Show your code for this new class.  Also tell us Flash Builder's complaint.  I assume that means a compiler error; which is most likely because you have either written invalid code or put code in an invalid place.

Comment: Hi, I added the code that I created. What do you mean with complaints? Theres no errors in the code. I do have some warnings but it is related to deprication in other clases and databindings where i have bind to a contant value. Those are the only 2 warnings that I have. My colleauge have the same code base and he is able to do so.

Comment: I don't know what I mean by complaints.  I was using your verbage: "the moment i hit save it complains about the "abc""

Comment: If there are no errors in the code; then what is your problem?  What question are you trying to solve?

Comment: sorry about the complaints part. i mean if i create an error in an existing class, the editor gives me an error. but in the newly classes that I add there is never and error. not even if i type in ABC.
The reason why i am asking this... I added a class. Did my changes and when i run it i got a runtime error. when i look back in the code i could see a silly mistake of mistyping another class i reference. In all my existing classes the editor gives me an error if i do the same thing. thats how  i came to this conclusion.

Comment: In earlier versions of Flash Builder--like the one you have--your classes won't be parsed for errors unless it was used or explicitly included in the SWF via a compiler argument.  In a Flex Library Project, the file isn't parsed for errors unless it is added to the final SWF.  Are you using a library project?  If so, is your new class set to be included in the SWC? ( In the project properties you should see the list of classes included in the library ).

Comment: Please confirm if this happening in Flash Builder 4.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this is default behavior  but what i have found is that...

If I change an existing class the compiler checks the syntax but if I add a random file the compiler will only check the file if that file is used by my application.

I have tried this and it seems to work. The moment that you call that file from within your application it validates and give me errors where should be.

Thanks for all your updates

Answer (score 0):

Flash Builder is plain stupid. The ide does not translate the ActionScript into an abstract syntax tree when typing, only check for the syntax when saving.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is an answer to the question.

Comment: The thing is upon saving I can see that flex is building the project on existing classes. but when i add a new one and hit save... there is no attempt to event build the project.